# Handling switching connection from two computers to one LCD screen

Tags: connection, hdmi, lcd, dvi, multiple-computers

I have the following equipment:

- Dell UltraSharp U2412M Monitor with LED
- Stationary HOME PC
- Ultrabook Samsung Series 9 NP900X4C
- USB Mouse
- USB Keyboard

Here is the diagram of how I currently have this items connected:

[image: Diagram]

Now the switching between different sources (Ultrabook and HOME PC) is inconvenient. I have to do two things:

1. I need to take USB OUT, that comes from LCD and plug it out of one computer and into the other computer. That is how I get to use the same keyboard and mouse even if on different computers.
2. Then I need to switch between Input Source on the LCD manually (from DVI-D to DisplayPort or vica versa).

Now I am searching for the solution of how I would be able to switch more efficiently. I was thinking of some kind of a box, that has all the inputs (USB, HDMI, DVI) and on the other side outputs, where USB is doubled. Now with the switch of a flip it changes currently active outputs. That way it would select only one USB and LCD with AUTO detect setting ON would identify which input source is currently active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a [**KVM switch**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch). They come in all sorts of configurations, including the one you're looking for.

Comment: I knew there had to be something like this. Thanks for the answer!